# Ask question on photography difficult to read

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Compare the regular site's "Ask a question" with the meta site's ask a question on photography.

[image]

It's very hard on the eyes..can this color be changed.  I didn't want to join photography to post this so Im posting it here...feel free to move to the site's meta if the developers look there?  I didn't think the developers were active on the photography meta site so I posted here.

Comment: Color schemes are such a pain... I first thought this was on the main Photo.SE site, and downvoted your question. Then, noticed the question on the sidebar over on the left of the screen, showing it on meta site here, and clicked it. So, found out the question actually IS on the Photo.meta site, and changed my vote from downvote to upvote. That's life. We are visual creatures, and translating the visuals into something understandable is a task. Sometimes a hard one, sometimes an easy task. :)

Answer (score 4):

Largely, *shrug*. I agree it's not the greatest piece of visual design in the world, but we (both photo.SE and the SE devs) have bigger problems to worry about. For avoidance of doubt, I *would* care if it were on the main site, but I'd be prepared to bet than 99% of people who even get as far as reading meta know how to ask a question, so aren't going to be confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, orange-grey is not the best color combination for this.

Would be great if a designer could be assigned to change this. Obviously, this is of very low priority, but then it's also not looking like too much work. Maybe it can be squeezed into a gap in a schedule somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem for me is it doesn't all fit on the grey background (depending on zoom levels in the browser).

[image: Ask question]

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any real need to change it. We're talking about two words, not text that you spend any amount of time reading or looking at, so the lack of contrast between the text and the background isn't a major problem. The orange and light gray are meaningful because they're complements of the blue and dark gray used on the main site, so they let you know at a glance that you're looking at the meta site. If developer resources were unlimited it might make sense to address the issue, but there are so many other things that should be fixed before worrying about this.